# With XCode 8.x how do you clone an existing target?

Tags: ios, xcode8

With XCode 6.4 I could easily clone an existing target. However this functionality doesn't seem to be available in XCode 8.x. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Select your target, right-click on it, then select `Duplicate`.

[image]

As you can see - the project now has 2 targets:

[image]

Comment: This answer is missing one step that had me confused and probably the OP. The panel the answer is showing may be hidden. You have to click on the 'blue square' icon above the word 'Project' to toggle it. Only then does this become obvious.

Comment: (you can see this blue square in the op's first picture in the top left, but if you don't have it clicked on it'll be black instead)

Answer (score 7):

I could not figure out what I was missing. **The above answer is missing a step**. The panel where you can duplicate targets is probably hidden.

[image]

Click the side panel button to see the targets.

Now you can see the targets and right click to duplicate, then just click on the name and rename it. Much easier.

[image]