# Add Bundle Items for specific Scheme?

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle

I would like to add some bundle items just for a specific scheme. I could create a run-script, but there i am unable to read out the current scheme.

Is there another chance to add some bundle files only for a specific scheme in Xcode 9.x?

Comment: Do you use .xcconfig files? If you do, you could have your files named differently (perhaps after your scheme names) - and have a variable in xcconfig with the name of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In script you can get your current build configuration.

You can duplicate your current build configuration, this will save all your settings for that config. After that rename your new config and refer to it in your scheme you would like to add bundle items to (there is no need to use separate scheme, you can say that, for example, you want to add that resources only for running. In that case just set your new config to Run build configuration of your existing scheme).

After you have all set up you can check on specific config in your run-script like this:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "BetaDebug" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "BetaRelease" ] ; then
// Do something specific for that config
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "ProductionDebug" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "ProductionRelease" ] ; then
// Do something specific for that config
fi
```

where `"${CONFIGURATION}"` is config name.

Answer (score 7):

Run the script like this after `Copy Bundle Resources` phase:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
cp -r ${PROJECT_DIR}/Settings/production/Settings.bundle "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't add a file just for a specific scheme using Xcode 9, but You can create a new target duplicating the other one, and you can configure your particular scheme to build that special target. In this way you can add files just to the special target (and indirectly to the special scheme) For target duplication it's very easy to do. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644593/1754559)

[Here](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/) you can find a tutorial on how to use targets to manage development builds Vs production builds.

Hope this answer your question.